# There are $7$ empty seats on a bus and four people get on. How many different ways can they be seated?

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are $7$ empty seats on a bus and four people get on. How many different ways can they be seated?

Would it be ${}^7C_{4}$ or ${}^7P_{4}$?

Comment: One question to ask is how many choices for a seat does the "first" person have, then how many will the "second" have, then the "third", and the "fourth".  Does the order of how they are arranged among the four seat matter?  If _not_ , then you would have to divide the product you found by the number of ways four people can be arranged, say, in a line.  If you can tell the difference among the possible way these people can be arranged in the seats, then you _don't_ divide by that number.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can distinguish between permutations and combinations. Suppose four people sit down on the bus in one way, then those *same four people* get up and change seats. Does this count as a different seating for you? If yes, you should use permutations (7P4). If not, you should use combinations (7C4).

This idea carries over to similar problems. If you are placing the items on a shelf (i.e. the order in which they appear matters), then permutations are appropriate. If you are placing the items in a bucket (i.e. the order in which they appear does not matter), then combinations are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is $$ 4! C_7^4 = 7 * 6 * 5 *4 $$ Where the C is a notation for the combination of 4 out of 7. Explanation: first you pick 4 out of 7 seats which will be taken and then you determine the person for each seat.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do . . . especially to make it more visual:

Call the people A, B, C, D, and call the empty seats E, E, E.

See how many choices you have for each seat:

```
choices: 7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Using the Fundamental Counting this gives 7! = 5040

But, since all those empty seats are considered "repeated letters", you have to divide out 3! to adjust for the 3 repeated "E's"   3! = 6

```
5040 / 6 = 840 ways the people can be seated.
```

Comment: Readers might find it helpful, when posting an Answer to such an old Question, if you were to highlight what new information or insight you will provide with your post.  At a minimum it would help to acknowledge whether you are getting the same or different values than the (now three year old) previous Answers.